# Is Entity Framework also persistance layer?

Tags: entity-framework, persistence, layer, 3-tier

OK. I know that Entity Framework is ORM. We use it for mapping data from database to object model, and from objects to relational data. But where it fits in a context of persistance layer? Can we say that persistance layer is also Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say - No! There are a lot of articles about this topic. But in general you don't want your object-relational mapper to be data-persistent. In fact exactly the opposite, keeping it persistent ignorant you can benefit by using your data classes with different types of data providers such as relational databases, web services, XML files and what not.

To keep data persistence you may take advantage of different design patterns like `Repository pattern` and `Unit Of Work` so you can really decouple you business layer from your data layer.

[image: Logical structure]

Ok, to make myself clear since it's very difficult through comments, here's an update to what I wanted to explain. Please have in mind that this is just my interpretation, and the way I'm using EF, I've been using it in different projects (desktop and web) but it's not universal, but still covers a lot of the most common scenarios.

So since I'm a big fan of `Code First` I'll write from this prespective. The `Database Model` is where your entities lies. Later on based on those entities the `EF` will generate your database. So what is important on this stage of development - you want to have you database normalized and you want all navigation properties set correctly. Not so trivial tasks as it may seems but that it's, you just care about how efficient your database will be.

Now comes the tricky moment somehow you should deliver you data to the business layer and it's true - as far as we are talking only about data from a database using repository is very arguable. However even then the one advantage that you get when having this `Repository` between the data and the business logic is that you don't have to take in mind the business needs while creating the data model, and after that this doesn't make it any harder to use your data from inside the business layer  even though what exactly will your front end looks like at the time you create the database model.

So at this point let's consider again the example case where in you `Database Model` you have those two entities - `Customers` and `Orders`. When a user log in into your application and wants to see his orders you need to join two tables in order to provide the front end the information that it needs. Option 1 - you don't have a Repository and you are using the `DbContext` directly from the method that returns the data. That means two things - you gonna have to write the same code everywhere you need to get this specific piece of information and 2 - if the business requirements change and in the same view that since now was used to show a customer and his orders now you have to show some additional info which is taken, let's say from a third table, then what happens - you have to go to each place where you use this view and change the way you retrieve the data. And option 2 - you have Repository, all your methods for accessing data are stored there and the `Business Layer` is completely ignorant about the way it get's the data, the `Database Model` is also ignorant about the needs of the business model which lead to loose coupling and only one place where you gonna have to make changes if you have to. In the scenario above, if you indeed use Repository and in your repository you have method called `GetUserOrders()` and inside this method you make the database call, the joins and so on, and all that the `Business layer` needs to do to get the data in the proper way is call this method when the requirements change and you have to include one more table, this time you don't have to look for all the places where you are using this data, you just have to modify one method and that's all.

It's pretty much the same logic on the way back. When you have some complex data returned from your front end and you want to save/update the old data with the new one, again - you can do it from the business layer but it leads to the same problem as when you have to get data, instead - you just pass the complex data to another Repository method which knows how to deal with it (say maybe some of the data should be saved directly into database and other should be used to feed a web service or whatever scenario comes to your mind) and here again - when something change, like - you want to use more heavily web services or the opposite, you want to migrate to more database centric design, all you have to do is change the method that takes care about the data the is concerned with this changes and nothing more.

So even though when I'm writing this I can see that `DbContext` can very well act as a repository and in this regard also as a data persistent layer, there are still some valid reason to not let this happen. Especially right now when the web services are more and more popular, `WebAPI2` is out and RESTFull services are frequently used I think that leaving the `EF` as persistent ignorant as possible is the way to go.

But yet again, this is my opinion. There are a lot of articles on this topic so I urge you to google and read about it, since I think this is very important part form the architecture of every application.

P.S

In response to your comment which was written while I was writing my edited answer:
`If I change data source I need to make changes in DAL anyway or in my example in repostitory.` - the answer is yes. But there is no way tho change the data source without changing the DAL. The question is how easy will be to do that. I think the with what I've written already you can decide for yourself which way is better but just because I really think this is one of the few really strong arguments of leaving the `EF` persistent ignorant all write it again. When you have Repository and there are methods which take care for data manipulation, every time something related with the way the data is fetched affects only those methods and nothing else. If you use the context freely, in your business layer even a little change may cause you a lot of trouble just because it always possible to miss something, you have to go through the entire code to make sure that you have fixed all places and it's just not as efficient as having all in one place.

Comment: Ok, but in code in my repository when I say context.Table.Where(x => x.ID > 8).ToList() I use EF context to get(persistance) and map data(ORM). Is that correct?

Comment: @user2457382 Yeah, that's why your question is a little bit subjective. I personally like the `Repository pattern` and think that still there's difference which makes me say that EF does not work as a persistent layer. But those that tell that `DbContext` is actually a repository also are somewhat correct so it's really impossible make a clear distinction. It's just that I would never use `context` directly like in your example and yes - you can make EF act like a persistence layer but my opinion is that it's better to keep it persistence ignorant.

Comment: @user2457382 There is almost no difference but the main reason I wrote - "No" and I think that EF should be persistent ignorant is this part - `context.Table..` What if you need to change the data source for this exact piece of information, say from querying a database table to reading XML file. Using the context directly like this will lead you to difficult maintaining and a lot of places to change code. But if you have another, layer - data access/persistence layer, than it's getting pretty easy. That's the main reason I prefer to use EF as persistent ignorant.

Comment: So, you have repository layer and below it data access/persistance layer? In persistance layer/data access you use DBContext to make CRUD operations via LINQ against database? Finally, can I say that repository pattern is something like business logic layer?

Comment: @user2457382 So I just share my opinion with you because I'm also interested in `Entity Framework`. Your question is not of `Yes/No` type. Sorry if you were expecting such kind of answer. I've wrote you what I think about it, and provide my arguments. I'm sorry that more people didn't wrote too so it can become a real conversation.

Comment: @user2457382 Nope, `Finally, can I say that repository pattern is something like business logic layer?` No it's your mediator between the domain model and the business model. A very simple example - imagine table Customer and table Orders - you need to show on the front end the orders for an user. Here comes the Repository. In your database model you don't care how the data should be displayed, in your business logic, you don't want to depend on how data is fetched. And the repository is the place where you inject this logic.

Comment: When in your repository you have method `GetOrderdsForCustomer()` the business model should not know how exactly you get this data, and you should not bend your data models to reflect the business need, you just normalize your database or use that web service and then use the Repository method as a place which decouples those two domains. For me - this is the beauty of using it and why you better leave EF persistent ignorant and create another layer that takes care about it.

Comment: Bussines logic layer calls repository which calls repository. Then repository translates result from BLL (domain model) to bussines model. Is that your way?

Comment: If I change data source I need to make changes in DAL anyway or in my example in repostitory.